# Mesh in object mode shows up with 0 vertices, help?

Tags: mesh, vertices

I got some weird issue, in object mode my selected mesh has 0 vertices etc
[image: https://vgy.me/PlzqWt.png]

but in edit mode it shows the correct number of vertices(gewijzigd)
[image: https://vgy.me/yCMVsT.png]

when I export the mesh it shows up empty as if there isn't anything
Anyone got an idea what's causing this ?

Comment: It also shows 0/0 objects which is weird because I can select them all in my viewport.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason there was only 1 layer in the scene selected in the render layers tab which caused this issue. I've selected them all again and the issue fixed itself.

[image]